# When using pygal.maps.world is there a way to format the numbers that display a country's population?

Tags: python, number-formatting, pygal

I am using pygal to make an interactive map showing world country populations from 2010. I am trying to find a way so that the populations of the country display with commas inserted ie as 10,000 not simply 10000.

[image: What my map currently looks like; you can see how hard the populations are to read.]

I have already tried using "{:,}".format(x) when reading the numbers into my lists for the different population levels, but it causes an error. I believe this to be because this changes the value to a string.

I also tried inserting a piece of code I found online

```
 wm.value_formatter = lambda x: "{:,}".format(x).
```

This doesn't cause any errors but doesn't fix how the numbers are formatted either. I am hoping someone might know of a built in function such as:

```
wm_style = RotateStyle('#336699')
```

Which is letting me set a color scheme.

Below is a the part of my code which is plotting the map.

```
wm = World()

wm.force_uri_protocol = "http"

wm_style = RotateStyle('#996699')
wm.value_formatter = lambda x: "{:,}".format(x)
wm.value_formatter = lambda y: "{:,}".format(y)
wm = World(style=wm_style)

wm.title = "Country populations year 2010"
wm.add('0-10 million', cc_pop_low)
wm.add("10m to 1 billion", cc_pop_mid)
wm.add('Over 1 billion', cc_pop_high)

wm.render_to_file('world_population.svg')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `value_formatter` property will change the label format, but in your code you recreate the `World` object after setting the property.  This newly created object will have the default value formatter.  You can also remove one of the lines setting the `value_formatter` property as they both achieve the same thing.

Re-ordering the code will fix your problem:

```
wm_style = RotateStyle('#996699')
wm = World(style=wm_style)
wm.value_formatter = lambda x: "{:,}".format(x)
wm.force_uri_protocol = "http"

wm.title = "Country populations year 2010"
wm.add('0-10 million', cc_pop_low)
wm.add("10m to 1 billion", cc_pop_mid)
wm.add('Over 1 billion', cc_pop_high)

wm.render_to_file('world_population.svg')
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you for explaining my error.